# How to Remove URL from www.example.com/2020/70 to www.example.com in a WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, url, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

In My WordPress website,  lots of URLs automatically generated; I want to remove these URLs:

- [www.example.com/2020/03](http://www.example.com/2020/03)
- [www.example.com/2020/02](http://www.example.com/2020/02)
- [www.example.com/2020/05](http://www.example.com/2020/05)
- [www.example.com/2020/06](http://www.example.com/2020/06)
- [www.example.com/2020/07](http://www.example.com/2020/07)

Comment: You can use a plugin like [WordPress SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) to disable monthly archives. That should remove those unwanted URLs you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks, @Kirk Beard, Disabled monthly archives from Yoast SEO Plugin. All unwanted URLs automatically removed.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin like [301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/eps-301-redirects/) can help you manage and create 301, 302, 307 redirects for your WordPress site to improve SEO and visitor experience.